# Selenium Actions not working with version 3.141.59

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch, action, pom.xml

The main issue is that we are trying to update our `POM` to use version 3.141.59 of `Selenium`. During our update we noticed that we have several errors with `Actions`. Upon reading documentation we found that:

> "import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;" has been deprecated
>   and replaced with "import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action".

We want to keep the same behavior and update our code to work with the new import. We have not seen any new documentation of how to actually use it. Below is an example of how we were using the old Actions.

```
try {
       Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
       actions.moveToElement(searchDocument);
       actions.sendKeys(PDF);
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       actions.build().perform();
    }  catch(Exception e) {
}
```

I was able to find this note in the change logs on Selenium:

> Deprecated the original Actions API in favour of the W3C approach.

Comment: `package org.openqa.selenium.interactions;

/**
 * Interface representing a single user-interaction action.
 *
 */

public interface Action {
  void perform();
}
` that's all I see under Action interface.

Comment: I have seen the documentation of what you are talking about. The issue I have is the implementation of the new interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple example if it's helpful.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

// create the mouserover action
Action mouseOverOnElement = actions.moveToElement(linkMenu).build();

// get the back ground color before mouse over             
String bgColor = linkMenu.getCssValue("background-color");
System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);

// perform the mouseover operation        
mouseOverOnElement.perform();    

// get the back ground color after mouse over       
bgColor = linkMenu.getCssValue("background-color");
System.out.println("After hover: " + bgColor);
```

Selenium Doc: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Action.html

Comment: `Actions actions = new Actions(driver);` does not work, it throws an error.

Comment: I am able to use that without issue with latest selenium version 3.141.59 . Here is my maven dependency `<dependency>    
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>        
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>        
            <version>3.141.59</version>        
  </dependency>`

Comment: Yeah it tells me that I need to change `Actions` to `Action` and I am calling the selenium dependency the same way you are. I am confused as to why it would be working for you.

Comment: I was able to find this in the change logs "Deprecated the original Actions API in favour of the W3C approach", would you know how to use this at all?

Comment: still wondering why it's working for me when we both have the same version. Can you just add only selenium java dependency (remove all other) and see what happens.

Comment: I was able to do so and we found that it was the Appium version. If you update Selenium to the newest one you will need Appium 7.0.0 that we are using. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by @Tyler in the comment it works for me: I was able to do so and we found that it was the Appium version. If you update Selenium to the newest one you will **need Appium 7.0.0** that we are using.

Update the Appium version too 7.0.